# How do I find the number of lines of a file and input the number into the array size in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, count, java.util.scanner

this is a relatively simple question but I'm stuck for one hour for some reason. What silly mistake am I making??? Please help!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Program2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"));

        int count = 0;
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            count ++;
            scanner.nextLine();
        }
        int[] array = new int[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please be more specific about what isn't working, and what you're expecting to happen.

Comment: What errors are you getting? Have you debugged your code? What is your question?

Comment: You've done this already: (int[] array = new int[count];). You need to change scanner.hasNext() to scanner.hasNextLine()

Answer (score 0):

Ohh... I had to scan the file twice -.- FML...

Answer posted:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Program2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"));

        int count = 0;
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            count ++;
            scanner.nextLine();
        }

        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"));

        int[] array = new int[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = scanner1.nextInt();
        }
        for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And this is a limitation of arrays.  An ArrayList would be much better, as you don't need to specify the size when you make one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar using Scanner, i'd rather prefer user BufferReader. Here es my code, let's see if it's useful to solve your problem.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class CoountingLines {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("/Volumes/nuquer/work/numbers.txt")));
        String line;

        Integer count = 0;
        final HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        try {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                map.put(count, line.toString());
                count++;
            }

            final int[] array = new int[count];
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                array[i] = new Integer(map.get(i));
            }

            for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                System.out.println(array[i]);
            }

        } catch (final IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```